# sudoers file, allow running file as root

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

I need to be able to run the command `/usr/bin/evrouter` as root, without being requested a password.

See http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=HOW-TO:Gyration_USB_remote_in_Ubuntu_for_XBMC_using_evrouter#Set_Up_Sudo for the followed example.

my `sudoeurs` file looks like this:

```
lucian@lucian-P35-DS3:~$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
lucian  ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/evrouter

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

When running evrouter after changing the sudeurs file, i get this

```
/usr/bin/evrouter -d /dev/input/by-id/usb-TopSeed_Tech_Corp._USB_IR_Combo_Device-*                                                                                                
/usr/bin/evrouter: error opening device /dev/input/by-id/usb-TopSeed_Tech_Corp._USB_IR_Combo_Device-event-ir: Permission denied
```

---

Edit:
the output should be:

```
lucian@lucian-P35-DS3:~$ sudo /usr/bin/evrouter -d /dev/input/by-id/usb-TopSeed_Tech_Corp._USB_IR_Combo_Device-*
[sudo] password for lucian: 
device  0: /dev/input/by-id/usb-TopSeed_Tech_Corp._USB_IR_Combo_Device-event-ir: TopSeed Tech Corp. USB IR Combo Device 
device  1: /dev/input/by-id/usb-TopSeed_Tech_Corp._USB_IR_Combo_Device-if01-event-ir: TopSeed Tech Corp. USB IR Combo Device 
/usr/bin/evrouter: error querying device /dev/input/by-id/usb-TopSeed_Tech_Corp._USB_IR_Combo_Device-if01-ir: Inappropriate ioctl for device
/usr/bin/evrouter: error querying device /dev/input/by-id/usb-TopSeed_Tech_Corp._USB_IR_Combo_Device-ir: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Display name: :0
```

Comment: What is the output of `sudo /usr/bin/evrouter -d /dev/input/by-id/usb-TopSeed_Tech_Corp._USB_IR_Combo_Device-*`

Comment: @user84104 see the edits. It should be allowed to open the requested files

Comment: Your output doesn't show you running evrouter with sudo. What happens if you do that?

Comment: @BillWeiss see the edited part

Comment: No. We would like you show the 'real' output when running `sudo /usr/bin/evrouter -d ...`.

Comment: I saw you specified only the command `/usr/bin/evrouter` to the `lucian`. Why can you still `cat /etc/sudoers`?

Comment: If you run it as root (taking sudo out of the mix) does it work? That error message implies that something else is wrong here.

Comment: What you did wrong was that you still need to *call* `sudo` to run `evrouter` as root. `sudo evrouter -d ... etc` will work fine.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I've fixed this by setting `suid` on the needed application, even if its not very secure, its my local desktop, so i trust its safe:)

Comment: Note to anyone who may see this in the future - this isn't a good thing to do.

Comment: `suid` is evil. Don't do it! Don't do it! Don't do it!

Comment: i know its evil, but i got no helping answers i needed to get things done

Comment: That's because you asked the wrong question.

Answer (score 1):

You can narrow this down by starting with very broad sudoers permissions and narrowing it down.  First try this in your `/etc/sudoers`:

```
lucian ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL
```

if that works, try making it more restrictive:

```
lucian ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/evrouter
```

and then

```
lucian ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/evrouter
```

Also try putting lucian in the sudo group with `vigr`.  That should work, via the last specification in your sudoers file (although the permissions will be broader than what you want).

Als sudo should be logging to /var/log/messages or /var/log/sudo.log or similar.  Check the logs.

Answer (score -1):

I think you forget to add the end of line in your sudoers file :
`lucian  ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/evrouter -d /dev/input/by-id/usb-TopSeed_Tech_Corp._USB_IR_Combo_Device-*`
Acutally, you can only launch the command `/usr/bin/evrouter` without parameter.

Comment: If you don't define a parameter list you can supply any number of parameters to the command.

Comment: @Dom: adding a parameter list doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: See the sudoers man page, if you don't specify command arguments in the sudoers file, sudo will accept any arguments you specify when you run the command.